# Where is my SQL Server database located?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, localdb

For my school project I am creating in ASP.NET a very simple web CRUD application. My application works although in my opinion it should not.

In `web.config` configuration file I have this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Librabry" 
         connectionString="Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient " />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I created data initializer objects and assigned them in `Global.asax.cs`. These initializers should create database tables and data.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            // Code that runs on application startup
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
// My data initializers
            Database.SetInitializer(new UserDatabaseInitializer());
            Database.SetInitializer(new BookDatabaseInitializer());            
}
```

In `site.master` file I have this code:

```
<section style="text-align: center; background-color: #fff">
    <asp:ListView ID="categoryList"  
                  ItemType="Library.Models.User" 
                  runat="server"
                  SelectMethod="GetUsers" >
        <ItemTemplate>
           <b style="font-size: large; font-style: normal">
           <a href="/User.aspx?id=<%#: Item.UserID %>">
           <%#: Item.UserLogin %> k;lk;lk;</a>
           </b>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate> - </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
     </asp:ListView>
</section>
```

Every time when I run my application (Ctrl+F5) users are listed. Despite I change connection string (e.g. change database name) and so application should not connect to the database. It seems the database has been created {somewhere} but I cannot find where is its location. When I list (in SQL Server Management Studio) all existing databases my database doesn't exist there. I have installed on my computer both data storage engines - SQL Server Express edition and MS Local DB.

I am confused and have no idea where is my data located?

Comment: Could you post section of your code where you are connectnig to this database? It just might not use connectionsString that you are looking at the moment.

Comment: The point is I am not connecting to the database manually elsewhere (or I don't know about it). I only call mentioned code in Site.Master file and my User model file returns the data.

Comment: Check in code where "Librabry" connection sting appears. Just press CTRL+F and search for "Librabry". If you can't find any (except one in config) then it's most likely you are using another datasource, like xml...

Comment: No matching results in all project :/ How can I find out if am I using another datasource? Maybe there is connected MS Local DB file, but where?

Comment: If you are using local DB there should be "*.dbf" file inside your project folder. Here is sample: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/05/29/working-with-a-local-data-file-in-vs.aspx

Comment: No such files. What to do now? Start from beginning?

Comment: Try posting more code. Complete aspx and code behind.